# SQL Server differences values between 2 rows on each month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem with the creation of a SQL query.

The objective of this application is to make the difference between two values ​​defined the first of each month.

Here is the query that I have built:

```
SELECT 
   Date, 
   Compteur - (SELECT MAX(Compteur)
               FROM SnmpDataPages
               WHERE IP = t1.ip AND ( Date < t1.Date) AND Compteur IS NOT NULL) AS diff, 
   IP
FROM 
   SnmpDataPages AS t1
WHERE 
   Compteur IS NOT NULL 
   AND Date BETWEEN dateadd(YEAR, -1, CAST(getdate() AS DATE)) AND CAST(getdate() AS DATE)
ORDER BY 
   Date, diff DESC
```

This returns this output:

```
Date        Diff    IP
---------------------------------
2014-11-04  5075    149.0.15.40 
2014-11-04  1623    149.0.19.177
2014-11-04  1264    149.0.19.77
etc.
```

This request works correctly for "daily" differences, but not for monthly differences.. (I search to diff 1st record off each month..) and grouping subquery seems not possible...

The table `SnmpDataPage` is incremented each day with the ip of each peripheril in the parc and there counter (total pages)

Example:

```
id      IP          Counter Date        Model
-----------------------------------------------
28780   100.0.15.51 140064  2014-10-08  Lexmark
28781   100.0.15.53 243617  2014-10-08  Lexmark
28782   100.0.15.55 24101   2014-10-08  Samsung
28783   100.0.15.56 135907  2014-10-08  Brother

44000   100.0.15.51 200000  2014-11-08  Lexmark
44001   100.0.15.53 250000  2014-11-08  Lexmark
44002   100.0.15.55 24200   2014-11-08  Samsung
44003   100.0.15.56 230000  2014-11-08  Brother
```

The output as I need it: ( Counter (M-(M-1)) )

```
date         diff      IP
-----------------------------------
2014-11-08   59936     100.0.15.51
2014-11-08   6383      100.0.15.53
etc.
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide some sample data as well as desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Mocked up data**

```
create table #SnmpDataPage (id int, IPaddress varchar(50), TheCounter int, TheDate datetime, Model varchar(50))

insert into #SnmpDataPage values (28780, '100.0.15.51', 140064, '2014-10-08', 'Lexmark')
insert into #SnmpDataPage values (28781, '100.0.15.53', 243617, '2014-10-08', 'Lexmark')
insert into #SnmpDataPage values (28782, '100.0.15.55', 24101, '2014-10-08', 'Samsung')
insert into #SnmpDataPage values (28783, '100.0.15.56', 135907, '2014-10-08', 'Brother')

insert into #SnmpDataPage values (44000, '100.0.15.51', 200000, '2014-11-08', 'Lexmark')
insert into #SnmpDataPage values (44001, '100.0.15.53', 250000, '2014-11-08', 'Lexmark')
insert into #SnmpDataPage values (44002, '100.0.15.55', 24200, '2014-11-08', 'Samsung')
insert into #SnmpDataPage values (44003, '100.0.15.56', 230000, '2014-11-08', 'Brother')
```

**Query to do a diff on last month**

```
select  #SnmpDataPage.TheDate, #SnmpDataPage.IPaddress, #SnmpDataPage.Model,
        #SnmpDataPage.TheCounter - Allrecords.TheCounter as TheDifference
from #SnmpDataPage
    join (  select TheDate, TheCounter, IPAddress
            from #SnmpDataPage
         ) Allrecords 
            on  #SnmpDataPage.IPaddress = AllRecords.IPaddress 
            and datediff(month, #SnmpDataPage.TheDate, AllRecords.TheDate) = -1
```

**Results**

```
 TheDate       IPaddress     Model   TheDifference
2014-11-08    100.0.15.51   Lexmark      59936
2014-11-08    100.0.15.53   Lexmark      6383
2014-11-08    100.0.15.55   Samsung      99
2014-11-08    100.0.15.56   Brother      94093
```

This could be extended to add previous months as well.  If I add the following test data, it will return 8 rows in the results, showing the difference between 10-08 and 09-08 in the first 4 rows:

```
insert into #SnmpDataPage values (18780, '100.0.15.51', 40064, '2014-09-08', 'Lexmark')
insert into #SnmpDataPage values (18781, '100.0.15.53', 43617, '2014-09-08', 'Lexmark')
insert into #SnmpDataPage values (18782, '100.0.15.55', 4101, '2014-09-08', 'Samsung')
insert into #SnmpDataPage values (18783, '100.0.15.56', 35907, '2014-09-08', 'Brother')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This and let me know.

```
    CREATE TABLE #tmp
    (
        ID INT,
        IP varchar(50),
        [counter] INT,
        date DATETIME,
        model VARCHAR(500)
    )

    INSERT INTO #tmp     ( ID, IP, counter, date, model ) VALUES  (1,'100.0.10.11',140064,'2014-10-08','Lexmark' )
    INSERT INTO #tmp     ( ID, IP, counter, date, model ) VALUES  (1,'100.0.10.11',200000,'2014-10-08','Lexmark' )


    SELECT * FROM #tmp

    SELECT IP,MONTH(date),MAX([counter])-MIN([counter]),model FROM #tmp
GROUP BY IP,MONTH(date),model
```